# Angular app running localhost calling dotnet app on different port gets no-referrer-when-downgrade. Due to withCredentials?

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, cors, referrer-policy

I setup a new Angular app with Angular CLI and it runs on http://localhost:4200
I call webservices that I develop with dotnet core which runs on http://localhost:5000

I allowed CORS for the localhost setup. I am sure it worked in the past but now I get a

`no-referrer-when-downgrade`

error message in chrome.

It somehow has to do with `withCredentials: true` 
If I put false then it works fine.

How can I pass credentials on http calls to a different port on the same localhost domain?

Comment: It would help to find out what specific request is causing this error and what is the protocol (http, https) of the client and the server.

Comment: it's just on localhost my local dev machine client is http://localhost:4200, server running at http://localhost:5000 I used to have WithCredentials: true in previous apps, so I used it here also and ran into the described problem. the request is just a httpClient.get (but same happens with .post I suppose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was no no-referrer-when-downgrade issue but a CORS issue.
I was missing the AllowCredentials() in the CORS policy

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // add cors
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "MyCorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(s => s.Contains("localhost"))
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try to upgrade your .NET Core application to HTTPS.

The `no-referrer-when-downgrade` message indicates that the default referrer policy is in place as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy).

> no-referrer-when-downgrade (default)
>
> This is the default behavior if no policy is specified, or if the
>   provided value is invalid. The origin, path, and querystring of the
>   URL are sent as a referrer when the protocol security level stays the
>   same (HTTP→HTTP, HTTPS→HTTPS) or improves (HTTP→HTTPS), but isn't sent
>   to less secure destinations (HTTPS→HTTP).

Just for a test you might try to set the referrer policy for development environment to a different value (this code uses NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware):

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseReferrerPolicy(opts => opts.UnsafeUrl());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested your solution and that gave me lot of insights. But in the end it was a dead end. I was just on the wrong track. sorry. NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware is pretty cool. thanks for that!

Comment: Glad you found the solution.